# Upload Image to localStorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, base64, local-storage

I'm curious if it's possible to upload an image directly to localStorage (for a Chrome extension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

1. But you will **store** image there, not **upload** it.
2. You should be careful with image size. Safe maximum size is around 500 KB, and around 2MB is a guaranteed crash, when you attempt to load it.

Comment: Thanks! I've decided to go with the HTML5 Fileystem API for my purpose: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Maybe others will be interested in doing the same.